# Get windows XP, windows 7 current login User Name in VC

Tags: api, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp

I want to get current login user name in windows xp, windows 7, in c++.
How can I do this? Is there any handy API without authority problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Win32 API [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx) or [GetUserNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435(VS.85).aspx) if you want a little more options.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
char sz[256];
GetEnvironmentVariable ("USERNAME", sz, 256);
```

Comment: set USERNAME=AnyFakeNameIWantToMakeUp.